# Application.GetContentStream returns null for content Uri

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, uri

I have file "sample.xml" in my project set as content.

I am running this code:

```
  Uri uri = new Uri("/sample.xml", UriKind.Relative);
  StreamResourceInfo contentStream = Application.GetContentStream(uri);
```

Why it returns null contentStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means probably that it does not find the file. Is the path correct?.

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo
>
> A StreamResourceInfo that contains a content data file that is located at the specified Uri. **If a loose resource is not found, null is returned.**

Comment: The path is correct. But I have tried all the variations and still the same.

Comment: @husayt this may seem obvious, but are you sure you want to load a `.xml` file instead of a `.xaml`?

Comment: @husayt take a look at this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/81FE0552-540C-4D7B-B732-6904B5F2120D (the last comment). Change the xml extension to something else and retry.

Answer (score 3):

You must set file's `Build Action` as Content, and `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`.

[image]

Comment: What you say is required if the file should be kept outside of the assembly and accessed through normal IO methods. The question is about ressources embedded into the assembly.

Comment: You're mixing resource files with the content files. Content files are standalone files that have an explicit assoiation with the application and resource files are embedded in the assembly. You can't retrieve a resource file with "Application.GetContentStream". You must use "Application.GetResourceStream" for embedded resource files.