# Application.GetResourceStream called on a Content Resource still return null

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, embedded-resource

Here is the task-related part of the VS2010 project (Windows Phone) structure:

[image]

The code is being executed from DummyMediaLibProvider.cs:

```
public class DummyMediaLibProvider: IMediaLibProvider
{
    ...
    StreamResourceInfo albumArtPlaceholder = 
        Application.GetResourceStream(
            new Uri("../Images/artwork.placeholder.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

`artwork.placeholder.png` *Build Action* is set to *Content*.

Still, whenever I run the code, `Application.GetResourceStream` returns null.

What may be the reason for the resource not being read to memory?

I have attempted to delete obj directory of the project, did Clean and Rebuild, but so far nothing helped.

Update:

If I apply Build Action: Resource to artwork.placeholder.png, I can get the resource stream ok though.

P.S. This is not the duplicate of [Application.GetContentStream returns null for content Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918072/application-getcontentstream-returns-null-for-content-uri) since the last had the extension (particurarly .xml) related problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The path supplied `Application.GetResourceStream` isn't relative to the position of the class, but relative to the application package.

```
StreamResourceInfo albumArtPlaceholder = 
    Application.GetResourceStream(
        new Uri("Images/artwork.placeholder.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Would be the correct path. You can also try with a full pack URI. ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=vs.95).aspx))

And finally, `Resource` would be the correct `Build Action` for this.

Comment: Dropping the initial `/` was what did it for me. I also set mine to `Content` instead of `Resources` (checking the xap with 7-Zip after a build to verify the files were contained within).

Comment: I lost almost an hour until I found out what was the problem for me: Where you set the Build Action, you must also make sure that the "Copy to output directory" option is enabled.