# Null Reference Exception when StreamResourceInfo attempts to get a ResourceStream?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, io

I'm following one of the MSDN Introduction to Windows Phone Development labs, and have run into a problem with [this lab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_windowsphonenavigationandcontrolslab_topic3#_Toc311119302) (Introduction to Controls Available for Windows Phone Applications). The lab provides both the starting files, and the end files (i.e., what the program should look like upon completion of the lab).

The particular part of the lab that has me stumped is the point where I'm reading in a series of images from an Assets folder, then displaying them in a ListBox on screen. Whenever this code tries to run, it throws a Null Reference Exception:

```
public static BitmapImage GetImage(string filename)
    {
        string imgLocation = Application.Current.Resources["ImagesLocation"].ToString();

        StreamResourceInfo imageResource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(imgLocation + filename, UriKind.Relative));
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(imageResource.Stream);

        return image;
    }
```

I've dug into as much as I can, and imageResource always winds up Null somehow, and I can't for the life of me figure out where it's going wrong.

I've included a link to the two projects [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19417676/Ex2-IntroductionToTheControls.zip) (129 MB, sorry for that). Everything under the "Begin" folder is what I've done so far (and throws an Exception when I attempt to navigate to the Images page during runtime). Everything under the "End" folder is what it's supposed to end up looking like, and is functional.

I'm very new to C# and WP7 development, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it just can't find the file? What does new Uri(imgLocation + filename, UriKind.Relative) give you?

Comment: Are you sure the URI is correct, relative to the package?

Comment: @MaxDataSol - new Uri(imgLocation + filename, UriKind.Relative) gives me Assets/Images/Butterfly.jpg as expected.

Comment: @JonHanna - As far as I can tell, yes. The folder containing the assets in question is Assets/Images in the package. Though I'm not totally familiar with VS2010, so it's possible I'm misreading, or misunderstanding how the pathing is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you set your images directory in `App.xaml` file, there is a mistake in the tutorial. You should set the application resource, `ImagesLocation` like this:

```
<system:String x:Key="ImagesLocation">Begin;component/Assets/Images/</system:String>
```

Where `Begin` is your project name `;component/` is needed as separator, and finally the `Assets/Images/` is the relative path to your images directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the build for the .bmp to "Resource".

Here's a couple of links explaining it:

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/238891.aspx/1

[Application.GetResourceStream called on a Content Resource still return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394282/application-getresourcestream-called-on-a-content-resource-still-return-null)

Comment: It looks like the all the images (they're .jpgs, if that's significant in any way) already had their Build Action set to Resource. Tried changing them to something else and back again anyway, to no avail.

Comment: What's the Copy To Output Directory setting? Try changing it to Copy Always or Copy if newer.

Comment: The Copy to Output Directory was set to "Do not copy". Changing them to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" still results in a null reference.

Comment: Found this link: http://www.silverlightexamples.net/post/How-to-Get-Files-From-Resources-in-Silverlight-20.aspx. It says that VS2008 has a bug that prevents the compiler from rebuilding the resources. You can work around that by go to the project folder, find and delete all the *.resources files in the subfolders. You can also just delete the 'Obj' folder. Now hit F5 to build the solution.

Comment: It also says that the Copy to Output Directory should be set to "Do not copy"

Comment: Hmm...nope, no dice there either (and I'm using VS2010, but I was being optimistic). Changed the imgaes back to "Do not copy", tried deleting the resources and building, as well as deleting the entire obj folder.

Comment: Can you try doing a simple IO operation on your file to make sure that its not the file path that is a problem?

Comment: Looks like the path is fine. Added the image to the MainPage.xaml with the line 
`<Image x:Name="TestImage" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/Images/Butterfly.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Height="Auto"></Image>`, and it appeared. Manipulated it in the MainPage.xaml.cs with a simple 
`TestImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;` which worked okay.
Let me know if this wasn't a valid test (i.e., if I needed to do the entirety of the i/o manipulation in C#) because, like I said, I'm new to this.