# How to show html file with background image in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone

I want to load local html file in web browser with background image which is also local.please anybody help me how to do that.

i am using below code to load local html file in web browser.

```
var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("images/Company.html", UriKind.Relative));
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream))
            {
                this.wb1.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
```

i am showing background image as below in html file

```
   body{

       background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
       background-size: 100%;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If bg.jpg is not too large you can provide it as a data-uri embedded in the css or in the html.

In the css:

```
li { 
  background: 
    url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7)
    no-repeat
    left center;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
}
```

In the html:

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```

The examples above taken directly from:

http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: its not working. i have already tried this one.anything else?

Comment: That's very odd.  Well here's a different SO answer that might help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394282/application-getresourcestream-called-on-a-content-resource-still-return-null

Comment: I suppose it may have to be read in as a separate resource stream.  So read in the html as you do, then do another stream for the image, but then the step of getting the image into the appropriate location in the html I'm not sure.